# Failed to locate library: libGLESv2.dll

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, lwjgl

I'm having issues getting my IDEA IntelliJ workspace to work with a Gradle script that should setup LWJGL and other libs automatically. The script does setup the workspace and everything compiles without issues. The problem is when running my code I get missing a missing .dll error.

Log of error: http://pastebin.com/P8e7AgVW
build script: http://pastebin.com/XSmskKyj

Checking the folder the code outputs the .dll shows the file is missing. The problem is that LWJGL should auto extra .dlls according to the site. https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/1.2.-Install

In short, I have no clue what I'm doing and could use help getting LWJGL setup. As well I have googled setup instructions, watched videos, and searched for error help. Everything is either not related or outdated for the current version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if LWGL 3.1.1 includes libGLESv2.dll and its companion libEGL.dll.

If they were not provided by LWJGL you can use the [PowerVR SDK](https://community.imgtec.com/developers/powervr/installers/) GLES emulator, which runs on top of your native OpenGL.

Another option is [Google's ANGLE](https://github.com/google/angle), wich runs on top of DirectX 9 and/or DirectX 11. Angle is lighting fast and runs very well on low end GPUs -I mean notebooks with Intel GPU-. If you are in hurry or would like to skip compiling ANGLE from sources, just go to your Chrome web browser install folder and look for **libegl.dll, libglesv2.dll** *and* **d3dcompiler_47.dll**.

Once you already choosed your OpenGL ES emulator, put above files in your PATH and/or java.classpath and be happy. In your case, seems the native path is set at *org.lwjgl.librarypath* and assigned to folder *C:\Users\Rober\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjglRober\3.1.1-build-16*.

Comment: There are others OpenGL ES emulators, but ANGLE and PowerVR are reliable **AND**  the license friendly, allowing free distribution without issues. Please read theirs licences just to confirm this.

Comment: I went with copying the .dll from chrome install, it seems to have worked as my code itself is erroring instead of missing file error. As well I searched though LWJGL's site and github. It doesn't seem to include the .dll or note that it has to be installed separately. Seems to be a bit of a problem for those new to the lib package. Anyways thank you for your help :)

Comment: @DarkGuardsman, that is good news! I also use [Microsoft's branch of ANGLE](https://github.com/Microsoft/angle), which adds some interesting features. Check out MS link and their links. But for plain OpenGL ES developments, the PowerVR and original ANGLE are OK.

Comment: @DarkGuardsman, [this presentation](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-686) is about ANGLE and the MS works on it.

Comment: I'll have to read up on it, right now I'm going to take things slow since I'm still rather new to LWJGL and rendering in general. Also https://twitter.com/DarkGuardsman/status/842037653302333440 my code works \0/ its not much but after 4 days of work its good.